# Why variadic macros are not supported by the standard?

Tags: opencl

The standard says:

- Variadic macros and functions are not supported.

I can understand it could be difficult to inline a variadic function, since the device may not have a call stack. But why not variadic macros? It's just an ability of preprocessor, even cannot be seen by the compiler. Could some one explain why khronos do not support variadic macro, while many OpenCL implements based on LLVM which is already able to process it without any additional modification?

Another doubt,

- Predefined identifiers are not supported.

what does they mean `Predefined identifiers`? Am I prohibited to write things like `#define M_PI 3.14`?